# Header size in monthview of Telerik Radscheduler

Tags: telerik, radscheduler

I want to increase the header size in month view of Telerik Radscheduler where (Sun, Mon, etc.) are displayed.

How to implement it??

Answer (score 2):

Use FireBug or IE dev toolbar to inspect the rendered html of the month header and see which style from the embedded skins you have to override. I did that for one of the scheduler live samples and here is what I found (see the sections in asterisks):

```
<table class="**rsHorizontalHeaderTable**" style="**width: 100%; height: 25px;**" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">----Month header week days-------------------</table>
```